# Modify Windows Bootloader to boot to SDCard

Tags: windows, bootloader

Is it possible to modify the windows bootloader to boot another OS installed on a sdcard.  The computer I have does not detect the sdcard as a bootable device in the bios.

Are there any other options that I might have to be able to boot to my sdcard?

Answer (score 2):

[Plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html) is your friend.

It will boot anything from anywhere regardless of what the BIOS thinks it can do.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll check it out when I have time.

Comment: It didn't work. Any other ideas?